# How to filter json response for specific text

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am using an API for a software where i wanna get the ID of something. When i make the get request using this code a

```
import requests
import json

url = "apiurl"
payload = ""
headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer .eyJ', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I get this response

```
{'current_page': 5, 'data': [{'id': 374047524, 'userId': 1295246, 'teamId': 24112628, 'name':
```

and a lot more info

What i wanna get is only the 'id' part

So if i request for multiple api info not just a single one i just wanna see
output

```
374047524 
374047525
374047526
```

I tried using some json filters and whatever but i cant make it work. Please help!

Explained already above.

Comment: `response.json().get("data").get("id")` ? -  you should be able to open the response as json (python dictionary) and perform selection / filtering on that

Comment: @MatthiasMertens `data` is an array ==> `get("data")[0].get("id")`

Comment: Or to get them all `list(map(operator.itemgetter("id"), response.json()["data"]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert your text into a python dictionary using `response.json()`, in the example below:

```
data = response.json()
```

Then, loop over the `data` list inside the dictionary to print those IDs.

```
for item in data['data']:
    print(item['id'])
```

This should give you the result you want.

Comment: Thank you!!!!! That worked flawlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nice list comprehension for this:

`output = [entry['id'] for entry in response.json()['data']]`

Comment: Thank you too, Jovan! Your solution also works perfectly!